# Marshalling special characters with Apache XML Beans

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have a schema which I use [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to umarshall to Java objects. I have no control over the the data that comes through.

One such field looks like `<Name>Barnes & Noble</Name>`.

Parsing fails at the character `&` with lexical error. Is there a way to specify an option while parsing XML files to ignore some special characters?

Any help you could provide will be great.

Comment: XmlBeans is used for parsing XML, and that fragment is not XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is invalid XML. Ampersand must be escaped into "&amp;".

You can manually escape all ampersand before parsing it as XML but that may mess up other XML entities.

Comment: Yes ZZCoder is correct. the data sent was incorrect. It should have been <Name>Barnes &amp; Noble</Name>

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `<Name>Barnes & Noble</Name>`as XPL and then feed it into any XML process. [XPL is just like XML except that it allows XML's special characters in text elements](http://hll.nu/xpl/xpl1.htm).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `XmlOptionCharEscapeMap`.

From the javadocs:

> This class is used to set up a map containing characters to be
>   escaped. Characters can be escaped as hex, decimal or as a predefined
>   entity (this latter option applies only to the 5 characters defined as
>   predefined entities in the XML Spec).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>   XmlOptionCharEscapeMap escapes = new XmlOptionCharEscapeMap();
>   escapes.addMapping('A', XmlOptionCharEscapeMap.HEXADECIMAL);
>   escapes.addMapping('B', XmlOptionCharEscapeMap.DECIMAL);
>   escapes.addMapping('>', XmlOptionCharEscapeMap.PREDEF_ENTITY);
>
>   XmlOptions opts = new XmlOptions();
>   opts.setSaveSubstituteCharacters(escapes);
> ```

Comment: This suggestion would probably help when writing XML, but will not help when parsing XML.  The example given by the user is not valid XML, so it may not be possible to parse it with `XmlBeans`.